# Is it possible to make computer temporary storage?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb, storage

Weird question,

But is it possible to use your computer as a temporary storage via USB charger. I'm thinking I could use this to download files straight onto the computer from my phone.

Edit:
I mean using the PC as a sort of mount point for my android. This will be like having an SD card however I understand it would probably not be as fast as I want to do this with an USB Charger. I was possibly thinking of this to download files bigger that my phone and sd's capacity.

Is this in anyway possible?

Comment: USB Charger or USB Cable ? ... Please explain why you would want to do this !...    ...    ...   You could make a simple looping batch script, that just pulls your download folder every 30 seconds or something !

Comment: @NoobFood I like that but the download will not be complete on the computer. I want to do this as it could possibly be a cheaper alternative of an SD card.

Comment: That's a good idea ! .. You may be able to use OTG ( On the go ) to download on USB memory devices like an external HDD  or USB memory stick  .... ... but that depends on what phone you have !

Comment: OTG depends on your phone's kernel. For an adventurous alternative, instead, you need **ADB** installed on your computer, and a decent **curl** or **wget** in your phone. You'll then plug your phone to your computer, open a terminal in the latter and start ADB with `adb start-server`. After that, you'll need to issue `adb shell "curl <url>" > <output_file>` if using curl, or `adb shell "wget <url> -O -" > <output_file>` if using wget. Replace `<url>` and `<output_file>` with the appropriate URL and destination file name. The phone will download the file and send it via ADB in real time.

Answer (score 0):

MTP is the protocol in which the phone can transfer files from your phone to your computer (and vice versa). If it is a Windows computer, you should be able to plug your phone in and access and modify the files from the `computer` section in the file explorer. A pop up on your phone may ask you what protocol to use (for security reasons) and your phone's files can't be accessed until you select MTP. Macs don't support MTP (last I checked). You may also want to use a wifi file transfer app, if that is more convenient.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking about...

Comment: `I'm thinking I could use this to download files straight onto the computer from my phone.` MTP and wifi transfer do this. If this doesn't answer his question, the author can not accept my answer, and comment on my answer with a clarification, and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: From my understanding of your answer, you meant to just download the file from the PC and transfer it to the phone, wired or wireless. What I see OP attempt to do is sort of "mount" the PC to a mount point available on the phone, and operate the download from the phone itself, and have the download go to that mount point (which stores it onto the PC). Let's see how OP explains his ideas later...

Comment: @AndyYan yh that is what I need

Comment: MTP won't work for me, downloading and pulling the file out at the same time will mean you won't even have a file at the end.